# How to use JavaScript templates?

Tags: javascript, html, templates

As I go around on certain websites, I often view the source code, and on a few websites I've come across 'script templates'. They seem pretty good and rather easy to implement.

How would I go about using them? Can't really find any decent tutorials on the Internet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fairly simple. You define a `script` tag with an unknown type, normally something like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
   <div>
      ...
   </div>
</script>
```

Then you put it in your HTML.

Browser will ignore the content of the script for rendering purposes and won't try to execute it due to the non-standard type.

Then you just retrieve it by ID `document.getElementById('myTemplate')` and do what you please.

Comment: If I were to retrieve information from a JSON AJAX request, how would I put the information in there?

Comment: You'd use some sort of template engine. Underscore. KO (parts). Handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Enfusion Framework for perfect HTML templating.
You can template different dataTypes

http://www.enfusion-framework.org/